# One type argument expected for class Result<out T>

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I do not quite understand what to do in some cases.
Here I need to plug my own class "Result", but I do not know how to do that.

```
    @get:Rule
    val taskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val mockRepository: Repository = mockk()
    private val notesLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result>() //Here it is
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        every { mockRepository.getNotes() } returns notesLiveData
        viewModel = MainViewModel(mockRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should call getNotes once`() {
        verify(exactly = 1) { mockRepository.getNotes() }
    }

    @Test
    fun `should return error`() {
        var result: Throwable? = null
        val testData = Throwable("error")
        viewModel.getViewState().observeForever { result = it?.error }
        notesLiveData.value = Result.Error(testData)
        assertEquals(result, testData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Result` expects a type argument (see the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/)), so if, for instance, the type of the result in your case is `Note`, you should change the declaration to:

```
private val notesLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result<Note>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to specify the path to this file myself through import